# What do i use instead of .change to show or not show a box based on a list value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have my javascript working great in the inital page, where the person selects an option from a dropdown list - .change function kicks in and .show or .hide the next boxes based on what was selected.

The problem is page 2 - now the selection has been made and there is no change happening to trigger hiding the subsequent fields.
I want the next fields to be hidden if No

I've tried .show instead of .change
I've looked up all sorts of variations of this, but I'm finding people looking for how to get the .change event to work on page 1, now what I do on page 2 when the list field has already been populated.

Page 1 I have this code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#ctl00_mainContent_qtWfInstance_ctl00_ctl30_lstValues").change(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == "Yes") {
            $("#CustomFieldWrapper_1089_0_0").show();
        } else {
            $("#CustomFieldWrapper_1089_0_0").hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Page 2 generates this code:

```
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
        <option selected="selected" value="No">No</option>
```

This works perfectly if they change the list value in the ct130.
What I want to do is write the java for the next page, where No was the selected value so it checks for what the selected value is.  What do i put in instead of .change ?

Thank you!!

Comment: please share page 2 html and js code

Comment: Hi Alika - just following up. Was your question answered satisfactorily? If there is more I can help with, please add a comment below my answer, or edit your question to clarify what else you want to know. Otherwise, it would be great if you could choose a "best answer" (by clicking the checkmark beside the answer) to close out the question. If no answer provided helpful information, please add your own answer and select that as the best answer. *(You won't get any points for doing so, but that will close out the question.)* Thanks!